# Problem reading data from serial port in python

Tags: python, serial-port, device

I have a python program that is trying to read 14 bytes from a serial port that
are arriving very slowly.  I want want to capture all of the bytes in a
bytearray[14].  I understand there are new byte array features in python 3.0, but
I'm only running python 2.6.6.  Upgrading may have unexpected consequences so I have to
stick with 2.6.6.

Data only intermittently flows over the serial port. I get one message on the
port maybe every 2 minutes or so.  This data flows very slowly.  The problem I am seeing is
that my code does not relaibly read the data one byte at a time.   I want to frame this
data at exactly 14 bytes, then process the data and start fresh with a new 14
bytes.

Am I taking the wrong approach here? Advice?

```
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 1200, timeout=0)
    ser.open()
    print "connected to: " + ser.portstr
    count=0
    while True:
        line =ser.readline(size=14) # should block, not take anything less than 14 bytes
        if line:
            # Here I want to process 14 bytes worth of data and have
            # the data be consistent.
            print "line(" + str(count) + ")=" + line
            count=count+1
    ser.close()
```

Here's what I'm expecting: line(1)=� 0~ 888.ABC�    /ends in carriage return

----------begin output------

```
line(0)=0
line(1)=~ ??1. ABC �    # here get some multiple bytes and stuff gets out of synch

�ine(2)=
line(3)=0
line(4)=~
line(5)= 
line(6)=8
line(7)=8
line(8)=8
line(9)=.
line(10)= 
line(11)=A
line(12)=B
line(13)=C
line(14)= 
line(15)=�
line(16)=

#...
line(48)=
line(49)=�
line(50)=0
line(51)=~
line(52)= 
line(53)=8
line(54)=8
line(55)=8
line(56)=.
line(57)= 
line(58)=A
line(59)=B
line(60)=C
line(61)= 
line(62)=�
line(63)=

line(64)=
```

----------end output------

Answer (score 4):

The API documentation for PySerial says [readline()](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.FileLike.readline) reads until \n, or until size is reached. However, the [read()](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read) function says it will block until size is reached. Both of these functions say they will return early if a timeout is set.

```
Possible values for the parameter timeout:

timeout = None: wait forever
timeout = 0: non-blocking mode (return immediately on read)
timeout = x: set timeout to x seconds (float allowed)
```

Maybe try `timeout=None` instead of `timeout=0`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ser = Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 1200, timeout=0)
print "connected to: " + ser.portstr
count=0
while True:
     for line in ser.readlines()   
          print "line(" + str(count) + ")=" + line
          count=count+1

ser.close()
```

You might also be interested in the `line.strip()` function if you haven't used it. Also, emphasis on the **s** in `ser.readlines()`, different from `.readline()`.

Answer (score -1):

Change the baudrate.

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 9600, timeout=0)
```

to a compatible baudrate.

For getting 14 byte data :

```
data = ser.read(size=14)
```

Comment: What's your justification for suggesting a different baudrate?  OP's example showed receiving the data expected (just not all in one read), which indicates the baudrate is correct.